# Python 3 getting unique result base in date/time when multiple entry in the same date but different times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

Im new in python and i been looking for a solution for this problem
i sure the solution is simple but i haven't get my mind around it.
if have this out put from a print out lets say:

```
for x in data:
    print('x')

('Rodriguez, Cesar', '000500', '2018-05-15 8:09:12')
('Rodriguez, Cesar', '000500', '2018-05-15 12:09:12')
('Rodriguez, Cesar', '000500', '2018-05-15 12:09:12')
('Gura, Simon', '000501', '2018-05-15 09:09:12')
```

how i can get only one result for  each name and each code and with latest date.
so my result should look like this:

```
('Rodriguez, Cesar', '000500', '2018-05-15 12:09:12')
('Gura, Simon', '000501', '2018-05-15 09:09:12')
```

but the way i don't care if the answer is a tuple. it could be a list or anything.
the only thing i need is that filter by name, idcode and latest entry.
thank you all for the help
best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict and a loop like this:

```
latest = {}
for name, code, timestamp in data:
    key = (name, code)
    if key not in latest or latest[key] > timestamp:
        latest[key] = timestamp
```

The result in `latest` will be:

```
{('Gura, Simon', '000501'): '2018-05-15 09:09:12',
 ('Rodriguez, Cesar', '000500'): '2018-05-15 12:09:12'}
```

Note: this uses string comparison to compare timestamps. If your data really has time formatted without leading zero as in '8:09:12' then you'll  need to properly parse it using `datetime.strptime` or `dateutil.parser`.